# Prevent User Editing the Cell and Out of Stack Space Error

Tags: vba

I have total 114 rows of cells to protect. Each row contains both cells that I want to protect and cells that require user data entry.

I am getting a "Out of stack space" run time error by using the codes below. I'm just posting partial codes here as they are too many line of codes to post here.

It seems that I can only protect the cells from row 1 through row 95. Can someone please help?

Is there any better way to do the task I am trying to do?

Thanks.

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'Protection for the header fields
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Or Target.Address = "$B$1" Or Target.Address = "$C$1" Or Target.Address = "$D$1" Or Target.Address = "$E$1" Or Target.Address = "$L$1" Then Target.Offset(1, 0).Select
If Target.Address = "$A$2" Or Target.Address = "$C$2" Or Target.Address = "$E$2" Or Target.Address = "$F$2" Then Target.Offset(1, 0).Select
If Target.Address = "$A$3" Or Target.Address = "$B$3" Or Target.Address = "$C$3" Or Target.Address = "$D$3" Or Target.Address = "$E$3" Then Target.Offset(1, 0).Select
If Target.Address = "$F$3" Or Target.Address = "$G$3" Or Target.Address = "$H$3" Or Target.Address = "$I$3" Or Target.Address = "$J$3" Or Target.Address = "$K$3" Or Target.Address = "$L$3" Then Target.Offset(1, 0).Select


If Target.Address = "$A$4" Or Target.Address = "$C$4" Or Target.Address = "$D$4" Or Target.Address = "$L$4" Then Target.Offset(1, 0).Select
If Target.Address = "$F$4" And [$L$2].Value <> "Oph_Phase II_POC" Then Target.Offset(1, 0).Select

If Target.Address = "$A$5" Or Target.Address = "$C$5" Or Target.Address = "$C$5" Or Target.Address = "$F$5" Or Target.Address = "$G$5" Or Target.Address = "$H$5" Or Target.Address = "$I$5" Then Target.Offset(1, 0).Select

'Protection for row # 6
If Target.Address = "$A$7" Or Target.Address = "$C$7" Or Target.Address = "$D$7" Or Target.Address = "$E$7" Or Target.Address = "$F$7" Or Target.Address = "$G$7" Then Target.Offset(1, 0).Select

'Protection for row # 7
If Target.Address = "$A$6" Or Target.Address = "$B$6" Or Target.Address = "$C$6" Or Target.Address = "$D$6" Or Target.Address = "$E$6" Or Target.Address = "$F$6" Or Target.Address = "$G$6" Then Target.Offset(1, 0).Select


'Protection for row # 8
If Target.Address = "$A$8" Or Target.Address = "$B$8" Or Target.Address = "$C$8" Or Target.Address = "$D$8" Or Target.Address = "$E$8" Or Target.Address = "$F$8" Or Target.Address = "$G$8" Then Target.Offset(1, 0).Select

'Protection for row # 9
If Target.Address = "$F$9" Or Target.Address = "$G$9" Then Target.Offset(1, 0).Select
ENd Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that your triggering the worksheet change event in the code itself. Its just essentially another endless loop scenario. Not to mention selecting objects form the application itself is a bit of a bad idea if you can avoid it. Essentially, all your doing is using the module to move where the active crusor is, which seems liek more work than its worth. What is the actual requirement? or is this a nice to have feature?

Comment: The requirement is not allowing user to be able to select the cells that has formula in it. Thanks for pointing out the worksheet change event in the code. But it has been working until I added more codes for conditional change cell background color and change a read only cell to a data entry cell. Anyway I have put in an array which basically does the samething as the target.offset would do. Now the error message is gone.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you if you want to lock cell by range

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.locked

Comment: The cells that I am trying to protect contains calculated value. So the values changes in those cells. I've tried the Excel lock cell function and it doesn't work with the cells that I want to lock. So I'm assuming the lock range method will not work with my cells?

Comment: hello look this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455320/lock-unlock-a-variable-cells